# WCF ExtensionDataObject causes Entity Framework 4.2 to fail creating database

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework-4

I am trying to create a SQL CE 4.0 database using Entity Framework 4.2 and object first.

My classes are defined in a WCF service.

I have one base class:

```
public class BaseData
{
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int StatusTypeId { get; set; }
    public StatusType StatusType { get; set; }
    public RecordStatusEnum RecordStatus { get; set; }
}
```

and one inherited class:

```
public class JobType : BaseData
{
    public int JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

When the base class is serialized by WCF it adds an ExtensionDataObject property

```
    public partial class BaseData : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }
```

This causes EF to crash when creating a table from the JobType class with the following error:

No mapping specified for properties JobType.ExtensionData in Set JobTypes

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 3):

In your data context definition, override the OnModelCreating to ignore the class that the extensiondata property comes from:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `NotMapped` attribute on `ExtensionData` property to exclude it from mapping. You cannot persist this field.

Comment: How and where would you add the NotMapped attribute?

Comment: On the property which you don't want to map - in your case it is `ExtensionData`.

Comment: It's not a property that I created - It is created automatically in the proxy. I want to get rid of the property.

Answer (score 0):

In the `JobType` class, you can hide the inherited `ExtensionData` property by redeclaring it as `private`. To do this, you need to include the keyword `new` rigth after `private`. This tells the compilator that you want to hide the property from the base class, and use this declaration instead.

```
public class JobType : BaseData  { 
    public int JobTypeId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public int SortOrder { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; } 

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    private new System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
       get { return base.ExtensionData; }
       set { base.ExtensionData = value; }
    }
}
```

If `ExtensionData` needs to be public for some functionality using this class, you can do it in the same way using public instead of private, and add the NotMapped attribute like this:

```
    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false), NotMapped()]
    public new System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get { return base.ExtensionData; }
        set { base.ExtensionData = value; }
    }
```

This way, you don't change anything except adding the `NotMapped` attribute to the declaration.